# Configure JPA/Hibernate/PostgreSQL without XML

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm getting back into the Java world, and I'm trying to configure a new Spring web application with JPA, Hibernate and PostgreSQL.

I have found a lot of older examples with various XML configuration files, and I'm wondering if there is a preferred new way to perform this configuration without relying on XML file authoring.

Some of the things I need to configure are the hibernate sql dialect, driver, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following fragments into a class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableTransactionManagement`

Hibernate/JPA (edit the packagesToScan String):

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.XY.model" });
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    return em;
}

Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    return properties;
}
```

DataSource (edit username, password and host address):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/DB_NAME");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Transaction Manager:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Is the DataSource class imported from javax.sql?

Comment: Yes, it is javax.sql.DataSource. The implementation is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

Comment: Could you please guide on this issue ASAP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685804/how-to-make-database-configuration-configurable-of-persistance-xml-file-through/35686103#35686103

Answer (score 2):

If you're gonna use `spring`, i recommend to use `Spring Boot` which offers many auto configurations. you can use a `application.properties` for configuring `dialect`s and stuff:

```
spring.datasource.url = <jdbcurl>
spring.datasource.username = <username>
spring.datasource.password = <password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
```

Spring Boot provides a number of **Starter Packages** that make easy to add jars to your classpath. These Starter Packages simply provide dependencies that you are likely to need when developing a specific type of application. Since you're developing a possibly web application that requires data access, you should add these to your `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Basically, spring boot tries to **guess** how you will want to configure your application, based on the jar dependencies that you have added. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, provides the following key dependencies:

- Hibernate — One of the most popular JPA implementations.
- Spring Data JPA — Makes it easy to implement JPA-based repositories.
- Spring ORMs — Core ORM support from the Spring Framework.

You can explicitly configure JPA settings using `spring.jpa.*` properties. For example, to create and drop tables you can add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

You can read more about spring boot [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive response.  Is application.properties a configuration file?

Comment: Yeap, spring boot allows you to configure your apps in many ways, on of them is the `application.properties`. You can also use YAML files, environment variables and command-line arguments to configure your app.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I wish I could mark both as accepted.  I'm going to use Lukehey's answer for my current project and I may utilize your method on the next project to compare.