# how to make database configuration configurable of persistance.xml file through database.properties file

Tags: spring, java-7, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I would like to get confirmation on the query "Is there any way to make database configurations configuration through database.properties using in `persistance.xml`". Is the below possible?

My following configuration works absolutely fine,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="spring-data-jpa-krishna" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Address</class>
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Employee</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

but I've many environment to deploy the application codes like Dev, QA, UAT, SAT, SystemTest etc, so I wanted to make configuration like below
database.properties:

```
mysql.jdbc.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mysql.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
mysql.jdbc.username=root
mysql.jdbc.password=root
hibernate.show_sql=true
eclipselink.logging.level=FINE
eclipselink.ddl-generation=create-tables
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="spring-data-jpa-krishna" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Address</class>
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Employee</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${mysql.jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${mysql.jdbc.driver.class}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${mysql.jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="${eclipselink.logging.level}" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="eclipselink.ddl-generation" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This would help me to solve my overhead. But I wonder how `persistece.xml` would load `database.properties` in order to get **placeholders** properly?

This [How to externalize properties from JPAs persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935394/how-to-externalize-properties-from-jpas-persistence-xml) link has done it through JNDI, but I simply wanted to do it through database.properties file.

Edit-1:
Yes, I'm using spring-Context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- For consider the using of annotations foe defining Spring Bean -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- For defining Spring Bean -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.javabeat.springdata.beans" />

    <!-- For bootstrapping the Spring Repository -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.javabeat.springdata.repository" />

    <!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="registrationBean" class="net.javabeat.springdata.beans.RegistrationBean" />


    <!-- =======  WAY-1    ========= -->
    <!-- ===== Define EclipseLink JPA Vendor Adapter ===== -->
    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        =========== Read persistent.xml file from here  ===========
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-data-jpa-krishna" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.javabeat.springdata.*" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable Transactional Manner -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**Edit-1: I see below error now:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.javabeat.springdata.repository.EmployeeRepository net.javabeat.springdata.beans.RegistrationBean.employeeRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5d3c9c43' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d3c9c43': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider@6201c010] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'spring-data-jpa-krishna'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5d3c9c43' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d3c9c43': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider@6201c010] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'spring-data-jpa-krishna'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5d3c9c43': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider@6201c010] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'spring-data-jpa-krishna'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider@6201c010] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'spring-data-jpa-krishna'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: PersistenceProvider [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider@6201c010] did not return an EntityManagerFactory for name 'spring-data-jpa-krishna'
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 43 more
```

I made changes in pom.xml file:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <!-- <filters>
            <filter>database.properties</filter>    
        </filters> -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="spring-data-jpa-krishna" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Address</class>
        <class>net.javabeat.springdata.model.Employee</class>

        <!-- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm -->
        <properties>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${jdbc.mysql.url}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="${jdbc.mysql.driver.class}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${jdbc.mysql.username}" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${jdbc.mysql.password}" />

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: If you're using Spring, you could choose to **NOT** use `persistence.xml` and get the properties from `database.properties` to configure `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Comment: Also, you used `Eclipse Link` and `Hibernate` specific options at the same time, why?

Comment: Ali - Yes, I'm using spring, please see my updates below and spring-Context.xml file. May be Hibernate specific options could be irrelevant and not being used, above configuration is proof

Comment: You mistakenly copied my beloved `persistence.xml` twice.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Spring, you could choose to not use `persistence.xml` at all and configure the `EntityManagerFactory` through a `FactoryBean` named `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34636649/1393484) can give you an idea on how to configure a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

If you insist to use `persistence.xml`, you can add the `${...}` placeholders in your `persistence.xml` and use, say, Maven's **Resource Filtering** to populate the actual values. With this approach, you should define the *Property Values* as the Maven properties and you won't need a separate `database.properties`. In this approach, you should add the properties as maven properties, something like following:

```
<properties>
    <mysql.jdbc.driver.class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</<mysql.jdbc.driver.class>
    <mysql.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</mysql.jdbc.url>
    <mysql.jdbc.username>root</mysql.jdbc.username>
    <mysql.jdbc.password>root</mysql.jdbc.password>
    <hibernate.show_sql>true</hibernate.show_sql>

    <!-- You've got to be kidding me! -->
    <eclipselink.logging.level>FINE</eclipselink.logging.level>
    <eclipselink.ddl-generation>create-tables</eclipselink.ddl-generation>
</properties>
```

And by adding these to your build section in `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Every placeholder with `${...}` syntax in your resources in `src/main/resources` will be replaced with their actual value, i.e. those are defined in `properties` section in `pom.xml`.

Comment: Ali - Many thank you for this, please see my updates Edit-1

Comment: You should add those `properties` into your `pom.xml`

Comment: Could you please take a look at my code from https://github.com/test512/spring-data-jpa-krishna ? It's not working for me

Comment: I can fix your project but imo it's better for you to use Spring Boot. It would automatically configure most of these configurations on behalf of you. Take a look at spring boot, trust me, it's worth it!

Comment: Agree, Thank you, I will be defiantly trying for that soon. For now, please fixed this issue.